# Create dummy index.html inside a new MKDR directory

Tags: mkdir

I know this may be a silly question but i cant seem to find just a simple answer.

I have a php script that makes a directory for me when the user starts a new entry.
That directory holds photos for their gallery.

What i would like to do is also create One index.html file inside that new directory with a few lines of html code in it.

How do i do this?

Im guessing that the file would be made like so:

```
mkdir('users/'.$id.'/index.html',0755);
```

But how do i add the html into that index.html file?

Or do i have one file on the server and copy it over into there during the MKDIR process?

Anyways a really simple answer would be best as i am very slow in this learning thing.

Thank you 
John

New edits.....

```
<?php

$id = 812; 
mkdir('users/'.$id,0755); 
chmod('users/'.$id,0777);

$fh = fopen( "users/".$id, "w+" ) or die( "Couldn't open file" );
fwrite( $fh, "<html><head /><body><h1>It Works!</h1></html>" );
fclose( $fh );

?>
```

Its giving me this error?

Warning: fopen(users/812) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in stackoverflowtest1.php on line 9
Couldn't open file

Any ideas? I am on a wamp windows 7 server and not using ftp to edit files but just the www wamp explorer foler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which language you are using so you'll either need to update your question or forgive the lack of concrete code. `mkdir` is for generating directories and not flat files. To do that you'll need to open then the file handle then print the HTML lines to that handle and then close it.

A file handle is a pointer to a file. It allows you to manipulate the data in that file ( i.e. read or write it ).

example code:

```
$fh = fopen( "path/to/file/index.html", "w+" ) or die( "Couldn't open file" );
fwrite( $fh, "<html><head /><body><h1>It Works!</h1></html>" );
fclose( $fh );
```

The path to the file needs a file name as a target, sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: sorry the question is basically php related. Unless theres an easy way to add some html into a newly created index.html file then i may just resort to copying the file over when the directory is made. I dont understand the term handle? what does that mean?

Comment: Im getting this errorr: Warning: fopen(users/812) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in stackoverflowtest1.php on line 9 Couldn't open file. I have pasted my code above from what you gave me with my changes.

Comment: Its ok, im positive this works. I think i just need to test it on a real linux server environment instead of wamp installed on my windows 7 machine.